# setting a state to a function that returns another state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binding

I have two `states`, one `state` is set to a number and the other one is set to a `function` that `returns` the first state. I receive the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined

Here is the snippet:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 5,
      date: this.full()
    };
  };
  full = () => {
    return this.state.count;
  };
```

and here is the codepen link:
http://codepen.io/abdolsa/pen/wJXPqb?editors=0010

I think it might be a problem with `binding` but I have not been able to fix it yet.

Thank you

Comment: set the date to something like this : "this.full()" and you will realise that calling a function in the definition of your state might be the wrong way to do what you want

Comment: Why would you want to do this?!

Comment: @Tom Fenech He is trying to set the state to the outcome of the function full within the state definition.

Comment: I can read the syntax :) I just have no idea what the purpose of this would be. Anywhere that can use `this.state` can call `this.full` instead, if necessary.

Comment: Anyway here a working fiddle, take a look of it and you might realise the problem http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpXrrr?editors=0010

Comment: ok I have a game, the game generates a map with items based on the player's level. so function full can access the first state that is the level of the player, do some stuff and return a value.

Comment: To add detail to your question [edit] it.

Comment: I just need to access the value of a state inside a function

Comment: I here is the working example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWVJPQ

Comment: @user2472167 OK, you can do that, just don't put the accessor function inside the state, as it isn't necessary, and make sure that the correct `this` is in scope when you use the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong. Value assigned to this.state inside constructor is not availbale untill initial render. If you want to set state with other state value than do this inside `componentWillMount`  or `componentDidMount` method.

if you do something like this:

```
 full = () => {
    return 5;
  };//it will work.
```

**So the solution is,**

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 5,
      date: ""
    };
    this.full = this.full.bind(this);
  };
  componentWillMount ()
    {
        this.setState({date:this.full()})
    }
  full = () => {

    return (this.state.count);
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
        <h2>{this.state.date}.</h2>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: thank you, I will upvote it as soon as I get enough points :)

Comment: No problem. Do you understood the error reason? if yes, you can accept the answer.